Minimum necessary condition for normal subgroup in the case of finite group
I have some doubt understanding the following paragraph of a text on group theory.
"If $G=\langle X\rangle$, then for $N \leq G$ to be a subgroup normal it is enough that $N^x = N$ for all $x \in X$, and if $G$ is finite it is enough that $N^x \leq N$ for all $x \in X$ (since this already implies that $N^x = N$)."
For the infinite case, I suppose it is enough to show that if $N^x=N$, then if $g\in G$, then $g=x_1\dots x_n$ for some $x\in X$. So, $N^g=(((N^{x_1})^{\dots})^{x_n}$. But, $N=N^{x_1}=\dots=N^{x_n}$.Then $N=N^g$ for all $g\in G$.
If the infinite case is well done, I have doubts in understanding why it is required for the finite case that the conjugate of $N$ be a subgroup of N for all $x\in X$ as a minimum necessary condition. Let's say I've made a try, but I'm not sure if it's right. Anyway, in that attempt, I saw that the condition should have been that the set of $N$ be a subset of $N$, not a subgroup.

It's just cardinality.  $N^n \leq N$ implies $N^x=N$ because the conjugate will have the same order as $N$.

A bijective function can be defined between $N$ and $N^x$. For $N=N^x$, I don't see why it is necessary for $N^x$ to be a subgroup of $N$. I mean, the equality wouldn't hold even if you put as a condition that $N\subset N^x$ or $N^x \subset N$?

Notation: (1) Use \langle X \rangle for better angle brackets: $\langle X \rangle$. (2) Use \dots for ellipsis with good horizontal space around it. If you want to control vertical alignment (lowered vs. centered), use \ldots or \cdots.

What is the definition of a "normal subgroup" that you are using?

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ if $gH=Hg$ for all $g\in G$ or $H^g=H$ for all $g\in G$.

@MenuPrincipal: About your first comment, $N^x$ is always a subgroup of $G$. So if $N^x$ is a subset of $N$, it is a subgroup of $N$.

Some points:

Let $N$ be a subgroup of $G$. If $g \in G$, then $N^g := g^{-1}Ng$ is always a subgroup of $G$.
Furthermore $N^g$ and $N$ are always isomorphic subgroups, with an obvious isomorphism $N \rightarrow N^g$ defined by $x \mapsto g^{-1}xg$.
In particular $N^g$ and $N$ have the same cardinality.
Suppose that $N^g \subseteq N$. If $N$ is finite, then $N = N^g$, since $N$ and $N^g$ have the same cardinality.
In infinite groups, there can be examples where $N^g \subset N$, but $N^g \neq N$.

Let me also comment on the following from your question:

For the infinite case, I suppose it is enough to show that if $N^x=N$, then if $g\in G$, then $g=x_1\dots x_n$ for some $x\in X$. So, $N^g=(((N^{x_1})^{\dots})^{x_n}$. But, $N=N^{x_1}=\dots=N^{x_n}$.Then $N=N^g$ for all $g\in G$.

If $G = \langle X \rangle$ and $G$ is infinite, it is not always true that every $g \in G$ can be written in the form $g = x_1 \cdots x_t$ for $x_i \in X$. In general you will also need to use inverses of elements in $X$ as well.
To be precise, if $G = \langle X \rangle$, then every $g \in G$ can be written in the form $$g = x_1^{e_1} \cdots x_t^{e_t}$$ for some $t \geq 0$, $x_i \in X$, and $e_i \in \{1,-1\}$.
Now for what you are trying to do, note that $N^x = N$ implies that $N^{x^{-1}} = N$. (Prove this if you haven't already.) Therefore, we get the following:

If $N^x = N$ for all $x \in X$, then $N^g = N$ for all $g \in G = \langle X \rangle$.



"Suppose that $N^g \subseteq N$. If $N$ is finite, then $N = N^g$, since $N$ and $N^g$ have the same cardinality. "
So what the text in the book says is wrong? I mean, there they mention $N^x$ being a subgroup of $N$, but it should really say $N^x\subset N$.


No, it's not wrong. Note that $N^x$ is always a subgroup of $G$, as mentioned in the beginning of my answer. Thus if $N^x \subset N$, then $N^x$ is a subgroup of $N$.

I have made a mistake when expressing myself. I mean, instead of mentioning that $N^x$ is a subgroup of $N$, let's say that it could have been mentioned that it is a subset of $N$. (the fact that it is a subset already implies that it is a subgroup of $N$)

Sure. Because $N^x$ is always a subgroup of $G$, saying "$N^x \subset N$" and "$N^x$ subgroup of $N$" are basically the same thing.
